# Why can't I use cout to print an array of string values in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, cout

This is a code snippet from a pretty simple program I am writing. I am fairly new to C++, but have background in Java, so I may have preconceptions as to how printing values should work.  My problem is when I do this line:

```
cout << "Please enter the weight for edge " << verticies[i] << endl;
```

I get an error message saying that the operands do not match the designated operator for <<.  Basically it is saying I can't do  cout << verticies[i].

Why does this happen?

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string verticies[6] = { "AB", "AC", "AD", "BC", "BD", "CD" };
    int edges[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the weight for edge " << verticies[i] << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you include `<string>`?

Comment: When asking this kind of question, the EXACT text of the error is very helpful.

Comment: Get rid of `stdafx.h`, for small programs, precompiled headers are not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try including `<string>`, should be enough

Comment: Please mark this thread as solved

Answer (score 3):

You have to include header `<string>` that contains the definition of the class `std::basic_string` including `std::string`

It is this header where the `operator <<` is defined.

Also consider to use class std::map insted of the arrays. For exmple

```
std::map<std::string, int> verticies = 
{ 
   { "AB", 0 }, { "AC", 0 }, { "AD", 0 }, { "BC", 0 }, { "BD", 0 }, { "CD", 0 } 
};
```

If the code will not be compiled then explicitly specify std::pair in the initializer list. For example

```
{ std::pair<std::string, int>( "AB", 0 ), std::pair<std::string, int>( "AC", 0 ), ...}
```